# wpf layout question

Tags: wpf, layout, grid, stackpanel

```
<Window ... >
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>b1</Button>
        <Button>b2</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

how to make this look like this:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button>b1</Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1">b2</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

without using a grid

Comment: A stack panel doesn't behave like a grid because its not meant to be a grid.  Its meant to be a stack panel.  If it was meant to act like a grid it would be a grid.  Sorta like how buttons behave differently than text boxes and birds don't tunnel under my lawn.

Comment: What do you mean make it look like that? In what way?

Comment: i meant for the stackpanel to occupy the whole window, jut like the grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: Write a custom Panel and override ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride to simulate Grid behaviour.

StackPanel arranges each of its child elements to use minimal height (or minimal width if Orientation == Horizontal). StackPanel offers no properties to alter this behaviour. Grid on the other hand, unless indicated otherwise, will divide all available space evenly across each child (or rather row/column).

Answer (score 5):

You could try that :

```
<Window ... >
    <UniformGrid Rows="2" Columns="1">
        <Button>b1</Button>
        <Button>b2</Button>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

Not as flexible as a full blown `Grid`, but simpler to use...

Comment: Seconded. Can't believe i missed that.